# Xamarin Studio / MonoTouch iOS - Runtime Issues with NewtonSoft Json.net

Tags: mono, json.net, xamarin.ios

I thought I would give Monotouch a try. I want to deserialize JSON data using Json.net (System.Runtime.Serialization.Json is not included in monotouch). So I downloaded the json.net assembly from the [Xamarin developer center](http://components.xamarin.com/). When I run the application I get an System.IO.FileNotFound exception complaining that it could not find 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0'

I just referenced the assembly and attempted to use it as you would in VS. Is there more that I need to do? I notice a warning when I compile the project stating that the assembly uses a newer version of the .net framework than monotouch supports but since I downloaded it from Xamarine's site I assumed it would work.

I have also attempted to build this assembly myself from source but this has not worked out. The Json.net project references are broken and being that I am new to monotouch I'm not sure how to fix them.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Did you add the assembly using the Components folder in your Solution?

Chances are, you downloaded the component, but instead of adding the Xamarin one, you went to the references dialog and installed the system one which is compiled against your system .NET version, instead of the one modified to run on iOS.